# Why is $(\log(n))^{99} = o(n^{\frac{1}{99}})$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I am trying to find out why $(\log(n))^{99} = o(n^{\frac{1}{99}})$. I tried to find the limit as this fraction goes to zero.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (\log(n))^{99} }{n^{\frac{1}{99}}}
$$

But I'm not sure how I can reduce this expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\qquad \begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ (\log(x))^{99} }{x^{\frac{1}{99}}}
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ (99^2)(\log(x))^{98} }{x^{\frac{1}{99}}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ (99^3) \times 98(\log(x))^{97} }{x^{\frac{1}{99}}} \\
&\vdots \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ (99^{99})\times 99! }{x^{\frac{1}{99}}} \\
&= 0
\end{align}$

I used [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) law in each conversion assuming natural logarithm.

Comment: Important to note: this works because $99$ is *finite*; I have seen people hide $n$ applications of L'Hôpital in $\dots$. Also, be very wary of using the rule in the context of *discrete* functions; I have seen people (trying to) apply it to $n!$.

Comment: Please consider not [reinforcing behaviour that hurts the site](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question).

Comment: @Raphael: I think in the case of $n!$, $\Gamma(x)$ or Stirling's approximation could be used to make it suitable for applying  L'Hôpital for large $n$.

Comment: Go ahead and try; not only is the derivation of $\Gamma$ even harder to handle, but it is clear that L'Hôpital can not help for exponential functions: the derivations are (at least) as hard as the original functions. Stirling's formula, on the other hand, is usually a good idea. See also my [answer over here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/827/98).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: take $99$th root of both sides.

Answer (score 4):

Try a common trick: express both functions as $e^{\dots}$ and compare the exponents; if *their* ratio tends to $0$ or $\infty$, so does the original quotient (see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/827/98) for the full rule).

> $\frac{(\log n)^{99}}{n^{\frac{1}{99}}} = \frac{e^{99 \cdot \log(\log n)}}{e^{\frac{1}{99} \cdot \log n}}$